# rosjava_core + turtlesim = compatibility problems?

Tags: master, turtlesim, ros-hydro, roscore, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just wanted to test how the rosjava_core (java master) is able to handle communication between C++ nodes. So I tried to:
-launch java implementation of master (by simple script in my: [jroscore repo](https://github.com/jvitku/jroscore) )
-and start two turtlesim demo nodes

If I run (in 3 terminals) these commands in sequence:

```
./jroscore # launches ros master implemented in rosjava_core
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key 
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

The communication and everything works fine, but if I launch them in another sequence:

```
./jroscore # launches ros master implemented in rosjava_core
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node 
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
```

The rosjava_core throws this exception after launching the last one:

```
./jroscore
jroscore: Launching master server now, uri: http://localhost:11311/
jroscore: Server successfully launched on address: http://localhost:11311/
Oct 02, 2013 1:12:36 PM org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcErrorLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to invoke method registerPublisher in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: 
org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method registerPublisher in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: 
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
Caused by: org.ros.exception.RemoteException: 
    at org.ros.internal.node.response.Response.fromListChecked(Response.java:115)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.publisherUpdate(SlaveClient.java:119)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.contactSubscriberForPublisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:269)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.publisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:251)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.registerPublisher(MasterServer.java:225)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerPublisher(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    ... 6 more
Caused by:
org.ros.exception.RemoteException: 
    at org.ros.internal.node.response.Response.fromListChecked(Response.java:115)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.publisherUpdate(SlaveClient.java:119)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.contactSubscriberForPublisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:269)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.publisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:251)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.master.MasterServer.registerPublisher(MasterServer.java:225)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerPublisher(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
```

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit LTS
ROS: Hydro Full desktop installation
rosjava_core: hydro-devel

Do you have any ideas what could be the cause of this, probably some problem in rosjava_core?

Thanks in advance
Jarda

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86296/rosjava_core-+-turtlesim-=-compatibility-problems?/) by [jrd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3136/jrd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-21**:
I am unable to reproduce the problem since building jroscore already fails for me. I checked out jroscore and called "./gradlew installApp" which resulted in "Could not find property 'install' on root project 'jroscore'.". Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jarda!

We are seeing the same problem when mixing the Java master and C++ nodes.

Were you able to fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
We have been digging into this issue, and actually found two bugs in roscpp that are involved in this problem. We reported both of them and actually hacked the Apache XML library to workaround the roscpp issues.

The bugs were reported in /ros/ros_comm repo issue #335 and #334. (I can't paste links, sorry!)

Regards,
Lucas

---

Originally posted by [tulku](https://answers.ros.org/users/2276/tulku/) with karma: 51 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-01-15**:
The issue links: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/334 and https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/335 .

**Comment by [tulku](https://answers.ros.org/users/2276/tulku/) on 2014-09-09**:
These issues have been fixed, long time ago. This question should be marked as answered.